# How to get the IP prefix while we have subnet and IPv4 address using python-netaddr?

Tags: python, ip, python-2.7, ip-address, inetaddress

I am using python-netaddr library to work on IP Addresses and subnets. I read the full documentaion of netaddrd given: [Netaddr documentation](http://code.google.com/p/netaddr/wiki/IPTutorial#Representing_IP_Subnets). But didn't found any solution to my problem. I have a IP Address and subnet i want to get prefix for that ip by using both of them. So that i can print all of the ip coming into the subnet.

For example:

```
Ip Address: 192.0.2.0
Subnet Network: 255.255.255.0

It should return the prefix which is : 24
```

Comment: Where does 24 come from?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `IPAddress('192.0.2.0/255.255.255.0')`? You can get a list of all addresses in that subnet, with an example in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: Is `/24` is a way of represent the mask `255.255.255.0` which is also `11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000`

Comment: So you want to, given a dotted network mask, get the prefix length? The ip address does not make a difference here, does it?

Comment: IPAddress() does not support netmasks or subnet prefixes! That's why you need to use IPNetwork()

Comment: @Oliver I just gave a sample tested from online

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did it shows : IPAddress() does not support netmasks or subnet prefixes! See documentation for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get 24 you can use the following snippet

```
ip = IPNetwork('192.0.2.0/255.255.255.0')
print ip.prefixlen
```

But if you want list of all  addresses in the subnet it's easier to use:

```
ip = IPNetwork('192.0.2.0/255.255.255.0')
list(ip)
```

Answer (score 4):

With a given Netmask we can get the prefix with the function below:

```
def getPrefix(mask):
    prefix = sum([bin(int(x)).count('1') for x in mask.split('.')])
    return prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getPrefix(binary):
    prefixCount=0
    for i in (str(binary)):
        if(i == '1'):
            prefixCount+=1
    return prefixCount
```

This would return your "Prefixcount" if subnet is converted into binary format and given in input.

Answer (score 0):

The subnetmask is : 255.255.255.0
This is how i c it:  1 . 1 . 1. 0

255 is ALL the 8-bits are turned on. ie. ALL 1's. And 0 is ALL the 8-bits are turned off.
if you look at this subnetmask [255.255.255.0], the first 3 octets are ALL turned 'ON' while the last octet is turned 'OFF'.
Thus, counting all the octets that are ON in this case, 3 octets 
we can say:   255.255.255.0
               1 . 1 . 1 .0
               8 + 8 + 8 + 0 =24

Comment: Seems you could split it, `bitwise-and` it and join it back.